# Who introduced coins in India?

Tags: economy, india, numismatics, ancient-india

Which King or Kingdom first introduced the coins in India for trading (internal or external)?

Comment: Don't forget that Persia occupied the Indus Valley from ~520 B.C.

Answer (score 12):

"The first coins in India were minted around the 6th century BC by the Mahajanapadas of the Indo-Gangetic Plain, and certainly before the invasion of Alexander the Great in the 4th century BC. " *[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coinage_of_India#Post_Maha_Janapadas_period_.28600_BCE.E2.80.94200_BCE.29)*

"Earliest Kushan coinage is generally attributed to Vima Kadphises. " *[Quora](https://www.quora.com/Who-introduced-gold-coins-in-ancient-India)*

"The first documented coinage is deemed to start with 'Punch Marked' coins issued between the 7th-6th century BC and 1st century AD. These coins are called 'punch-marked' coins because of their manufacturing technique. Mostly made of silver, these bear symbols, each of which was punched on the coin with a separate punch." *[RBI.org](https://www.rbi.org.in/currency/museum/c-ancient.html)*

Answer (score 6):

[Copper coins have been found](http://www.thehindu.com/todays-paper/Significant-finds-at-Dwaraka/article14724351.ece) in the submerged city of Dwarka which has been dated to be at least [3000](https://www.quora.com/Epics-of-India-Is-it-really-true-that-we-have-found-Dwarka-City-of-lord-Krishna) to [10,000](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/world/south_asia/1768109.stm) years old.

Quoting from source one (the Hindu):

> Thirty copper coins were also found in the excavation area. The
>   structures found on land belonged to the medieval period. "We have
>   also found 30 copper coins. We are cleaning them. After we finish
>   cleaning them, we can give their date," he said.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: Sources are all embedded behind the words highlighted in blue colour.

Comment: Apologies; links are not displaying on my screen today. my comment was in error and I've deleted it and upvoted.

Comment: Nevertheless, links have a tendency to break and it would be a good idea to edit some quotes from your sources into your answer.

Comment: @Spencer: Quotation added in the answer.